# PHP text diff script

Tags: php, text, diff

Do you know of a good method/script for finding the text 'diff'?

Comment: No, but I'd like to. +1 +Favourite

Comment: See this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736771/how-to-do-text-diff-using-php)

Comment: You know what? There are dozens of this answer if you've ever google for it. Even already asked more than twice here in stackoverflow!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112523/calculate-text-diffs-in-php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736771/how-to-do-text-diff-using-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try using the [PEAR Text_Diff](https://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/) it provides a text-based diff engine and renders for multiple diff output formats.