# PHP - Differences between two pieces of text

Tags: php

I have two pieces of text! Every piece of text has some lines. Every line contains any sort of char/numbers;

I'd like to implement a PHP function that will tell :

1. if a line has been deleted or inserted from the original one;
2. if a line has been edited;

Example :

```
    Text 1              Text 2                 Result
    my name is marco    my name is marco       OK
    I'm 25              I'm 26                 Return 1
    I like football     I hate baseball        Make newline on Text 2
    I hate baseball     
    I'm cold            I'm cold               OK
```

I tried many ways to do it, but I don't know how to identify if a line is NEW or if it's just edited. Maybe I should trace some index when user write the text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP text diff script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178554/php-text-diff-script)

Comment: Could be a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/321294/234695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the PEAR package that find differences trough the text: [PEAR Text Diff](https://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/)

> PEAR Text Diff: Engine for performing and rendering text diffs

There's also [Simple Diff](https://github.com/paulgb/simplediff/blob/5bfe1d2a8f967c7901ace50f04ac2d9308ed3169/simplediff.php) which I don't personally know, IMO it's more trustable the PEAR package.

> Simple Diff: Given two arrays, the function diff will return an array of the changes.
>       I won't describe the format of the array, but it will be obvious
>       if you use print_r() on the result of a diff on some test data.

Comment: uhm yeah, in fact I'd like to implement my own function for this kind of analysis :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @markzzz, "your own function" means "the fucntion you are asking us to do"? If you are not that good at this kind of thing let premade mini-framework do that for you. The functions you are requiring to be done are somehow difficult to realize, you should accept the fact that the frameworks are better sometimes: this is one of this times. (Notice that both the mini-framework are suggested are very lightweight)