# Text Comparison using jQuery or PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have 2 strings as an example and want to see if the TEXT of both the strings are EXACT.If the STRING doesnt matches it should show which is the STRING or a sentence that is missing from the original string.

Is it possible in jQuery ? Any code ?

I tried to use lot of Online Text comparison Tools but none of them says that the following strings are exact and there is no difference, need to ignore Paragraph

Text 1

> ```
> In this chapter, you learn some real time-savers. If you are tired of defining
> the same layers, along with units, grid, snap, and ltscale, for each new
> drawing, read on. You are about to learn how to create your own template
> drawings. With templates, you can begin each new drawing with setups
> you have defined and saved in previous MEMA sessions, or with a
> variety of predefined setups included in the software.
> In addition, you learn to reshape the grid using the LIMITS command
> and to copy, move, and array objects on the screen so that you
> do not have to draw the same thing twice. We begin with the LIMITS
> command, because we want to change the limits as part of defining
> your first template.
> ```

Text 2

> ```
> In this chapter, you learn some real time-savers. If you are tired of defining the same layers, along with units, grid, snap, and ltscale, for each new drawing, read on. You are about to learn how to create your own template drawings. With templates, you can begin each new drawing with setups you have defined and saved in previous MEMA sessions, or with a variety of predefined setups included in the software.
> In addition, you learn to reshape the grid using the LIMITS command and to copy, move, and array objects on the screen so that you do not have to draw the same thing twice. We begin with the LIMITS command, because we want to change the limits as part of defining your first template.**
> ```

Comment: `the following strings are exact`/`there is no difference` ... but then `need to ignore Paragraph etc`. Which is it? And what is "etc"? Write a _thorough_ and _precise_ problem specification.

Comment: Yes but none of the online tool says that its same content

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a "Diff" implementation, which isn't completely trivial. It's possible in both PHP and JavaScript.

See these SO questions:

- [JavaScript based diff utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053587/javascript-based-diff-utility)
- [PHP text diff script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178554/php-text-diff-script)

To find more:

- [Search for "JavaScript diff" on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20diff)
- [Search for "PHP diff" on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20diff)

Comment: @user well, the two strings you show indeed aren't identical. The easiest way will probably be removing the line breaks before doing the comparison