# Easy code to compare two texts from the database

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do text DIFF using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736771/how-to-do-text-diff-using-php)

So I've got two texts to show up side by side, but I need to have it compare the two. Have a strikeout for all deleted words, an underlining for all added ones, that sort of thing. And it can't be too complicated because I need to do this for three text files in the same php file. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a trivial task. The keyword you are looking for is `diff`

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here http://www.weberdev.com/get_example.php3?ExampleID=4323
Additionally, this PEAR package may be of interested to you, however it's not maintained anymore: http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/